# What do you call a number that is a power of 2?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I know there is a term for a **number that is the power of 2**, such as 8, 32, 128, 4096 -- but it slipped my mind.

Comment: Just for the record - is there a reason you skipped every other power of two in your example?!!

Comment: I see what you mean, but 4096 doesn't fit that pattern. It's just a random selection.

Comment: Actually 4096 fits the pattern, because it's a power of 2.

Comment: @Alenanno: I think the pattern Joe meant was the standard sequence of powers of two are 2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512 .. and Jen used alternate powers in the post 8,32,128 and then jumped to 4096.

Comment: @JoseK: In his question he simply stated "powers of 2", so it fits the pattern, I suppose...

Comment: @Alenanno: yes it does, i'm only explaining what I thought the first 2 comments meant. more noise :)

Comment: I'd call them round numbers, but that may be a programmers affliction. ;)

Comment: @Alenanno Just for what it's worth.  Read my comment again.  It says "In your **example**", the example being: "8, 32, 128, 4096".  OK?

Comment: @Joe Blow, it doesn't matter his example, 4096 is a legit power of 2 in any case. I was writing against when he said "it doesn't fit the pattern", I wasn't replying to you.

Comment: @Aleanno by the way "Jen" is probably a female.

Comment: @Jen sorry to be patronising. Are you confusing *square numbers*  (numbers raised to the power of two) and *powers of two*?

Comment: @Matt No, I was looking for a term other than *powers of two* as they are so common in all matters digital

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A "power of two" seems like a good name.

Although 'exponent' has been suggested, it is **not correct**

The relationship is quite simple, though:

> **3** is the exponent which generates *the power of two*   **8**       (2<sup>3</sup> = 8)
>
> **12** is the exponent which generates *the power of two* **4096**  (2<sup>12</sup> = 4096)

Comment: Indeed. Any mathematical documentation I can find refers to them as powers of two.

Comment: "It's more precise than saying an exponent." - No, "exponent" would simply be **wrong** here, not just less precise.  Why did you even mention it?  It just muddies the waters.  I could understand it if Jen had suggested it, and you were making a correction - but you're just correcting yourself here.

Comment: @MT_Head, I agree. What I typed yesterday was just *fastest gun in the west* syndrome. I could edit my answer, but it seems a little late now.

Comment: @pavium - Feel free to edit your answer!  Remember, the whole reputation-points thing is (supposed to be) secondary to _giving correct answers_, not just for the OP but for future Googlers.  In this case, a straight edit would make your answer identical with @Digital Powers', but perhaps an explanatory note?  Future Googlers might not read the comments.

Answer (score 8):

In programming, especially graphics programming (textures), powers of two are sometimes referred to as POT, and non-powers of two as NPOT.

But obviously the word "pot" has strong connotations, and so this term can be used only in such a context unambiguously. Anywhere else, "power of two" is a much better choice.

Comment: Fascinating, @nikai, I have never heard that one. Can you see any examples of that online, just out of curiosity?  Cheers

Comment: Sure, here are two OpenGL specifications using it for texture dimensions: http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_non_power_of_two.txt http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/texture_rectangle.txt Here it is used in papers in context of ordering policy: http://or.journal.informs.org/cgi/content/abstract/58/2/492 http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=4737780

Comment: FANTASTIC REFERENCE, Nikai!  Awesome.  @Jen, @Nikai has a great term, even though little arcane.  I mentioned 3D graphics in my answer -- there's the term!!   How awesome.  Great stuff.